# Cube Processing vs Database Processing

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas

We have a SSAS database (SQL Server 2012 Enterprise) with 4 cubes in it. 1 of the cubes is significantly bigger than the other 3. We want to process the 3 smaller cubes at regular intervals during the day and update the large cube every night.

A really basic question, if I just process a selected cube, does that still process all changes in measure groups and dimensions that are included in that cube?

To put it another way, will the data in the cube that I process be exactly the same if I process just 1 cube or if I process the whole database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a huge difference.

If you process a cube then it processes the measure groups and partitions inside it.

If you process a database then it also processes the dimensions